# cast listView.SelectedIndices to List<int>

Tags: c#, listview, casting

Is there any way to cast `listView.SelectedIndices` to `List<int>`?
I tried this

```
(List<int>)reListViewAllMovies.SelectedIndices.Cast<List<int>>()
```

But it doesn't work (InvalidCastException).
If solution doesn't exist, is there any "one-line" solution for example using lambda expression?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Old question but I was looking for a solution myself. .NET v4.5. I don't know about earlier versions of the framework.

```
var list = myListView.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thanks. Works also in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

```
reListViewAllMovies.SelectedIndices.Select(i => (int)i).ToList();
```

Or, you could use a `foreach` loop to convert the results:

```
var newList = new List<int>();
foreach(int i in reListViewAllMovies.SelectedIndices)
{
    newList.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: there is no `Select` method

Comment: The loop of course works fine but I was trying to avoid this (without breaks - three lines long) solution. But thanks for effort anyway...

Comment: @klerik - What's wrong with loops? If you would take a look at the LINQ Select method, you'd see that it's doing essentially the same operation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the loops, I was just hoping that there will be some shorter solution...

Comment: `myListView.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().ToList();`